# Powershell multiline regex: subtitles , How?

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

At this website: http://softwarerecipes.blogspot.com/2011/01/powershell-script-for-fixing-subtitles.html.
there is script for fixing  offset of subtitles files like this:

SrtFixer.ps1 -Path 'Movie.srt' -Offset '-00:00:26.700'  but isn't available.

So i found a script in C# ( here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32834/Subtitle-Synchronization-with-C)

My first step is to write the right regex for the following structure :

```
2
00:00:01,775 --> 00:00:04,528
- I want you to admit what you are.
- You still refuse to see
```

I'll try this:

```
$file = "D:\subtitles\Hannibal - 02x10 - eng.srt"

$regex ='(?m)[0-9]{1,5}\n([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3}) --> ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]  {2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})\n((.+\n)*)'

$text =get-content($file) -Raw

$text | Select-String $regex -AllMatches |
    Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

The regex seems correct (regexhero) but not any matches.

Can you help me ?

**EDIT:**

My mistake. The correct regex

```
$regex ='(?m)[0-9]{1,5}\n([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})\s-->\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})\n((.+\n)*)'
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The regex isn't correct, at least when checked with [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) and your sample text. That's because `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]  {2}:[0-9]{2})` requires some odd spacing within the timestamps. Removing those provides a match for the sample input.

That being said, how about getting a *paid* version of the content? Those usually have subtitles in good order.

Comment: My mistake. The correct regex:     <br/>$regex ='(?m)[0-9]{1,5}\n([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})\s-->\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})\n((.+\n)*)'

  but it doesn't work.

Comment: @cool25 It works with the specified sample data. Thus, there is an error with sample, or your file contents aren't what you'd expect.

Comment: Answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653086/convert-c-sharp-code-to-powershell-scriptblock-delegate